# How to pass multiple variables from Angular JS using $http to PHP - ERROR [$http:baddata]

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angularjs-http

> I am using angular js and angular js ui-route. I am trying to pass a registration POST form variables from a view passed to angular and send to PHP using $http.POST.
>
> Here is my index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hostelry Services</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/custom.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="App">
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#!/">Hostelry Service</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#!/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Hostelries</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Compare</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#!signup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
              <li><a href="#!login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div ui-view></div>



    <!-- Library Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/angular-datepicker/dist/angular-datepicker.min.js"></script>


    <!-- JS route -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/homeroute.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

> here is my register.html

```
    <div class="row"  style="padding-top: 100px;">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="padding-left: 170px; font-size: 20px;">Register</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form method="POST" ng-submit="register()">
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="firstname" id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="Firstname"><br>
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="middlename" id="middlename" type="text" placeholder="Middlename"><br>
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="lastname" id="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Lastname"><br>
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="age" id="age" type="text" placeholder="Age"><br>
            <select class="form-control" id="sel1" ng-model="gender">
              <option></option>
              <option>Male</option>
              <option>female</option>
            </select><br>
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="address" id="address" type="text" placeholder="Address"><br>
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="nationality" id="nationality" type="text" placeholder="Nationality"><br>
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="username"><br>
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="user_password" id="user_password" type="Password" placeholder="Password"><br>
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="user_email" id="user_email" type="text" placeholder="Email"><br>
          <button type="submit" id="submitbutton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
          <p ng-show="user">{{user}}</p>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> here is my homeroute.js

```
    'use strict';

var application = angular.module('App', ['ui.router']);

    application.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        // For unmatched routes
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        // Application routes
        $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: './views/login.html'
            })
            .state('/', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: './views/home.html'
            })
            .state('signup', {
                url: '/signup',
                templateUrl: './views/register.html',
                controller: 'registercontroller' 
            });



    }
]);

    application.controller('registercontroller', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
                $scope.register = function() {
                    var firstname = $scope.firstname;
                    var middlename = $scope.middlename;
                    var lastname = $scope.lastname;
                    var age = $scope.age;
                    var gender = $scope.gender;
                    var address = $scope.address;
                    var nationality = $scope.nationality;
                    var username = $scope.username;
                    var password = $scope.user_password;
                    var email = $scope.user_email;
                    $http({
                        url: './services/loginsubmit.php',
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                        },
                        data: {
                            firstname: firstname,
                            username: username
                        }
                    }).then(function(data) {

                    });
                }
            }]);
```

> here is my loginsubmit.php

```
 <?php 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $response = [];

    $response['user'] = $_POST['firstname'];


    echo json_encode($response);

 ?>
```

> I dont know if the method I used in my $http was right. When I click my submit button it returns me this: [image: [$http:baddata]]
>
> it returns this in network tab

[image: Problem]

Comment: Please check that Network tab there to see what the server is actually returning. `$http:baddata` suggests that the response isn't valid JSON.

Comment: Please remove the `angular` tag if this is about Angular 1